# Placing in-text citations close to quote or avoid in-text citation redudancy?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am converting a paper from numeric citations to the Springer template (with in-text citations) and am not sure how to cite when a quote is at the end of a sentence:

> A: Roy et al (2019) did something and ... “had a strong preference for X.”
>
> B: Roy et al did something and ... “had a strong preference for X” (Roy et al, 2019).

I tend to think B is better because the reference is closer to the direct quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write:

> Roy et al (2019) did something and ... “had a strong preference for X”
> (p. 27)

... with the page reference just after the quote but with the author-year combination in the expected place. I think that this comports with the American Psychological Association guidelines.